# GRPC Exception sendHeaders has already been called

Tags: grpc

It seems that when the size of requests > 32k， the excetions will  appears. But I don't know why this happens and how to solve it.

```
   Apr 25, 2020 10:25:13 PM io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor run
    SEVERE: Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1OnReady@2f3f487b
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: sendHeaders has already been called
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:512)
        at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl.sendHeaders(ServerCallImpl.java:88)
        at com.xz.hosting.serverbase.request.RpcDispatcherModule$GenericRpcServerCallHandler$1.onReady(RpcDispatcherModule.java:336)
        at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.onReady(ServerCallImpl.java:307)
        at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1OnReady.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:755)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is there anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because it's a not thread compatible call.

[click here for details](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2313#issuecomment-250628978)